# What are the "native methods" of "transport client" in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, clients

Plz tell me--- Can we do Indexing and searching only using transport client (9300) or without using 9200 port at the endpoint? I check all documents but never see any native methods related only transport client. Help me to find out these methods.

Answer (score -1):

The best source of information is the source code itself.

You can find the `TransportClient` source code [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/42526ac28e07da0055faafca1de6f8c5ec96cd85/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/transport/TransportClient.java)

And since `TransportClient` extends `AbstractClient`, it also has access to all inherited methods from that class, which you can discover [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/42526ac28e07da0055faafca1de6f8c5ec96cd85/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/support/AbstractClient.java)

Comment: Thanks.. but is it possible that I dont use 9200 port in my application and do all indexing and searching via 2300 only.. even not at the endpoint.

Comment: Yes, you can do anything through the transport client (default port 9300)

Comment: Is there any performance regarding matter when we use 9300 port instead 9200?

Comment: 9300 uses the TCP layer and 9200 the HTTP layer, so it means you've less overhead.